# how do i display element 98 at random position inside the array in mips using syscall 42

Tags: assembly, mips, system-calls, mars-simulator, mips64

the following is an array in mips

.byte

16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16

16,12,12,12,41,22,22,22,22,25,16

16,12,12,12,21,22,22,22,22,25,16

16,12,12,12,21,22,22,22,22,25,16

16,12,14,14,83,42,24,24,24,24,16

16,12,21,12,98,32,32,43,34,34,16

16,12,11,13,12,32,34,23,42,32,16

16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,I6

I made mips code where when keyboard input is provided element 83 will move inside the array in any of  4 directions so when element 83 reaches element 98 . element 98 needs to be displayed again randomly in a new position inside the arIay. i did read through  a stack overflow answer for generating random numbers but those were not exactly helpful as those generate random number and i want to generate element 98 in random position.
i assumed the outterbounds where the total number of element in the array and t tried to write a code t=using syscall 42 but i was stuck in completing the code

#t0 is the array address

li $a0,98
la $a1,88 #outterbounds
li $v0,42
syscall
sb $a0,($t0)
addi $t0,$t0,1 #increase array address

Answer (score 1):

Note that according to [the documentation I found](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html), the random number is returned in `$a0` so you should not use that for your `98`.

```
li $a0, some-random-id # for random generator
li $a1, 88             # upper limit
li $v0, 42             # syscall number
syscall                # get random in $a0
addu $a0, $a0, $t0     # add base address to $a0
li $t1, 98             # the value
sb $t1, ($a0)          # store
```

Comment: what do i load $a0 with in this line (li $a0, some-random-id) @Jester

Comment: What it says ... just pick any number you like, it's selecting which `Random` generator to use. You can just put `0` for simplicity. See also the notes in the linked document.

Comment: Problem is that for the OP's situation, the array is a two dimensional, with bounds bytes included in the matrix, which means they may really want two random numbers (say x, and y) or row & column), and also that the OP has yet to show knowledge of how to do dynamic array indexing on this assignment.  I suppose they could use one random number and check what's on that square and repeat if has bounds byte or other non-blank.

Comment: If you're going to do `a[i]` for a one dimensional array or `a[i][j]` for a two dimensional array, you need an `i` or an `i` and a `j` that know where the 82 is. @coder  In the situation where the initial board is statically arranged, you can know the initial row and column values as constants. In another scenario, you can search the board (check each square) for the row and column having the 82 and when found, then capture the location in variables.

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get a correct random value in `$a0`?